# OpenMalaria installation; "Remote branch master not found in upstream origin"

Tags: github, installation, directory, mobaxterm

I am using MobaXterm to install OpenMalaria, as described in the following instructions: https://github.com/SwissTPH/openmalaria/wiki/UserGuide

I seem to be having problems with directories and install destinations on all fronts. I notice the destination path apparently already exists (perhaps because I've run `git clone` before). I don't know if this is related to the error I receive that prevents me from compiling the latest version.

```
  10/02/2022   21:51.03   /home/mobaxterm  git clone https://github.com/swisstph/openmalaria.git
fatal: destination path 'openmalaria' already exists and is not an empty directory.
                                                                                                                                                             ✘

  10/02/2022   21:51.21   /home/mobaxterm  cd C:/Users/User/Downloads/openmalaria-main
                                                                                                                                                             ✔

  10/02/2022   21:51.49   /drives/c/Users/User/Downloads/openmalaria-main  ./build.sh
Cloning...
./build.sh: line 81: [: rev-parse: binary operator expected
Cloning into 'openmalaria'...
fatal: Remote branch master not found in upstream origin
```

I've also tried running the executable in openMalaria-windows.zip from the latest releases (https://github.com/SwissTPH/openmalaria/releases) without success. This opens Windows command line, the following appears, and then the program closes again:

```
Error: Error: unable to open scenario.xml
In: scenario.xml
OpenMalaria: No such file or directory
```

I've run OpenMalaria.exe from MobaXterm with the same result.

How can I install and use OpenMalaria?

Comment: Those are two unrelated issues and none of them is due to MobaXTerm. One is GIT issue and the other one is openMalaria issue.

Comment: Understood. Should I separate this into two questions?